# Multiple file upload using fetch delay next requests

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native 0.41 with Redux and Sagas. When I upload images in Sagas (with takeEvery) using fetch (and FormData) the requests are somehow being sync or that seems so. If I try to do another request while uploading, then the request is delayed until some images are uploaded, not all of them. I can see this behavior because I log all Sagas and Redux actions and the flow is like this when I drop all images to upload and at the same time do an update request:
1- Image 1 success upload
2- Image 2 success upload
3- Simple update request (delayed)
4- Image 3 success upload

I've checked nginx logs and the request is not reaching server until firsts requests arrive.

I've tried moving requests to components (eliminating Sagas possible problems) but nothing works.

Thanks.